# What happens if you use L or C components in RF filters above their resonant frequency?

Tags: capacitor, rf, filter, impedance-matching, resonance

We have been optimizing filters (BP, HP, LP) by [dropping a set of .s2p files into Microwave Office](https://youtu.be/xbdBjR4szjE) and letting the optimizer choose what works "best", but I started to wonder if that was a good idea: What if the optimizer chose a "good" component but is being used above resonance in a way that just happens to move the Smith chart where it wants it?  For example, it might use a capacitor for its inductive qualities above resonance.

The graphs below show two different components from [muRata's SimSurfing site](https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/mlcc.html?lcid=en-us&jis=false&md5=044e76c970e0dd6a84ddb6741cc4e6b7) and effective capacitance begins to increase at 10-20% of the resonance frequency.:

- The left two graphs show a 10nF cap with a resonant frequency at ~85MHz
- The right two graphs show a 1nF cap with a resonant frequency at ~375MHz
- The top graphs show capacitance vs frequency
- The bottom graphs show S21 vs frequency.

Questions:

- Should filter components *always* be chosen so they resonate well above the target filter frequency to keep the value stable and linear? If not, what would be the exception(s)?
- When optimizing a filter and the optimizer finds a "good" component but the frequency is above the component's resonant point, is that still usable or could it cause unexpected behavior when the filter is constructed in real life?

  - Relatedly: are measurements in the .s2p that are above resonance "stable" in the sense of being repeatable from physical part-to-part, or will physical parts vary widely above resonance in random or unexpected ways?
- Other considerations?

[image: 1nF and 10nF S-parameter and capacitance graphs]

Comment: 1) A ferrite bead is chosen so that it's resonance occurs exactly where the bead filters best.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: frequencies of interest include the stopband, where resonances may occur regardless of component quirks (e.g., layout strays).  In that case, you want to keep any zeroes in that range a good margin below the minimum attenuation spec.  Or alternately, set a higher (say 10dB+) than required bound somewhere up in the cutoff range.  That allows for variance in the parasitics.

Mind that these effects are very sensitive to layout, compare series to shunt data for example: the former has a transmission line characteristic (flat within fractional dB up to very high frequencies; the plot doesn't show but the phase shift should be linear with frequency reflecting this real delay), while the latter has a pronounced series resonance (equivalent to a TL stub).  These are not so much intrinsic to the component, but to the geometry: the component has nonzero length and etc.  (To be clear, the ESL is this way; the little peaks and valleys on the slope are weird characteristics of the chip. If not part of the fixture, I suppose, but that should be well calibrated out.)

As for any optimization problem, carefully setting topology and constraints, and frequently checking output for whether those characteristics are being relied on or not, is prudent.

Answer (score 0):

The amplitude peaks and then falls off, so there is more attenuation, the rest of the graph looks something like this:

[image]
Source: https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/articles/1715-optimizing-power-distribution-networks-for-flat-impedance

Also, since most circuits are RLC, they start to attenuate more at higher frequencies so the frequency rolloff get's higher.